# CSS Body Tag Height Limits to Visisble Area Only

Tags: css, layout, height, overflow

I am redesigning this site: http://puffandpass.co.za/

with this design:

http://puffandpass.co.za/incubator/ (this is incomplete hey..)

**The Design has the following structure:**

```
 <html>

     <body>
            <div id="wrapper">
                     <div id="page">
                             *//content goes here*
                      </div>
            </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Now here is my CSS for each of the above tags:**

```
html, body          { 
color: #000;background: #3B5998; 
font:  10px Helvetica, Arial, Verdana,sans-serif; 
height: 100%; 
line-height: 1.5em;
text-align:center; 
}

#wrapper            { 
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #123569;    
border: 0.5em solid #123569;   
 height: 100%;    
margin: 0 auto;    
width: 102.4em;
}


#page               { 
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;   
float: left;  
text-align: center;    
width: 102.4em;
 }
```

**[The problem]**
The height of the `html, body` (and so the `#wrapper`) tags limits to the visible area of the of the screen. This means that the contents of the `#page` tag overflow outside the `#wrapper`. **The height gets worse  (smaller) when I have Firebug open.**

**Question:**
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `#wrapper`, change `height` to `min-height`.

Due to having `height: 100%` on the parent elements, this will force `#wrapper` to have a *minimum height* of `100%`, instead of the height being exactly 100% with no allowance to increase.

Then, on `#page` remove `position: absolute` and `float: left`.